# Three.js How to get an object's rotation relative to another?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a camera and an box. I want to get the camera's rotation as if it were a child of the box, without actually parenting the camera.

THREE.js has object.worldToLocal(position) which will correctly get the camera's position relative to the box, but that function will of course not work for euler rotations, so I'm looking for the equivalent for euler or quaternion rotation.

Unity has [transform.InverseTransformDirection(vector)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html), and I'm looking for something similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it!

```
  var rot = camera.getWorldQuaternion();
  rot.multiply(box.getWorldQuaternion().inverse());
  var euler = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion(rot);
```